# Copy Paste not working with headless browser in python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, firefox-headless

I am using selenium with python to click a button on a webpage. This copies data in csv format on to the clipboard. Then I use the data on clipboard to create an array, which is used further in the program. Everything works fine until I start the webdriver in headless mode. Is there any solution to the problem? Can this entire code be written without selenium? I am open to ideas and improvements in my code.

```
    try:
        objFFOptions = Options()
        objFFOptions.add_argument('--headless')
        objFFWebDriver = webdriver.Firefox(options= objFFOptions ) # start hidden
        #objFFWebDriver = webdriver.Firefox()
    except:
        print("Error in initiating the Firefox webdriver")
        objFFWebDriver.quit()
        quit()


    try:
        objFFWebDriver.get("https://chartink.com/screener/90dis")
    except:
        print("Error in opening the webpage")
        objFFWebDriver.quit()
        quit()

    # loop for waiting before query data loads
    intAttemptCounter = 0
    boolStockDataFetched = False

    while True:
        intAttemptCounter = intAttemptCounter + 1

        print("\tFetching attempt ", intAttemptCounter)
        try:
            objFilterMessageElement = WebDriverWait(objFFWebDriver, (intDelaySeconds * intAttemptCounter)). \
                until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'DataTables_Table_0_info')) or \
                      expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'dataTables_empty')))

            print("\tEither of the two marker elements found")

            if re.search(r"Filtered\s+[0-9]+\s+stocks\s+\([0-9]+\s+to\s+[0-9]+\)",
                         objFilterMessageElement.text) is not None:
                print("\t",objFilterMessageElement)

                try:
                    # click copy button
                    objFFWebDriver.find_element(By.XPATH, \
                                                "//*[@class='btn btn-default buttons-copy buttons-html5 btn-primary']").click()
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    if intAttemptCounter <= intMaxAttempt:
                        continue

                # store the query result from clipboard to a string
                strCSVData = pyperclip.paste()
                pyperclip.copy("")

                # create array from the csv string containing stock data
                arrDataList = list(csv.reader(StringIO(strCSVData),delimiter='\t'))
                arrFinalDataList = [arrDataRecord[2] for arrDataRecord in arrDataList[3:]]
                
                boolStockDataFetched = True
                break
            elif objFilterMessageElement.text == "No stocks filtered in the Scan":
                print("\t",objFilterMessageElement.text)
                break
            else:
                if intAttemptCounter <= intMaxAttempt:
                    continue

        except TimeoutException:
            print("\tTimeout Exception")
            if intAttemptCounter <= intMaxAttempt:
                continue
            else:
                break

    if boolStockDataFetched == False:
        print("Error in fetching records or no records fetched")
        
    objFFWebDriver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't copy-paste in a headless browser. You could, instead, read the data from the visual table.

However, you don't need Selenium at all anyway, if you use your browser's inspector to look at the requests the page makes, you can formulate something that does a similar sequence, like so:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
import requests

sess = requests.Session()
sess.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 Safari/537.36"

# Do initial GET request, grab CSRF token
resp = sess.get("https://chartink.com/screener/90dis")
resp.raise_for_status()
csrf_token_m = re.search(r'<meta name="csrf-token" content="(.+?)" />', resp.text)
csrf_token = csrf_token_m.group(1)

# Do data query
resp = sess.post(
    "https://chartink.com/screener/process",
    data={
        "scan_clause": "( {cash} ( latest count( 90, 1 where latest ha-low > latest ichimoku cloud top( 9 , 26 , 52 ) ) = 90 ) )",
    },
    headers={
        "Referer": "https://chartink.com/screener/90dis",
        "x-csrf-token": csrf_token,
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    },
)
resp.raise_for_status()
data = resp.json()
pprint(data)
```

This prints out e.g.

```
{'data': [{'bsecode': None,
           'close': 18389.5,
           'name': 'NIFTY100',
           'nsecode': 'NIFTY100',
           'per_chg': 1.28,
           'sr': 1,
           'volume': 0},
          {'bsecode': '532978',
           'close': 18273.8,
           'name': 'Bajaj Finserv Limited',
           'nsecode': 'BAJAJFINSV',
           'per_chg': 2.25,
           'sr': 2,
           'volume': 207802},
          ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AKX. I will have to research a lot to fully understand the solution you have provided. Like I have no idea what csrf token is? :) I tried to study the webpage code using the Web Developer Tool but I was not able to figure out how the data table is getting displayed. Is it Javascript code in atlas.js? I was not able to figure out where to look for the requests the webpage makes. Is it somewhere in the "Inspector Tab" of Web Developer Tool?

Comment: Okay I think I understood where to look for the requests this page makes. Web Developer Tools -> Console -> GEThttps://chartink.com/screener/90dis. But how did you figure out the "sess.post(..." code. How did you find the query string ("scan_clause")?

Comment: Depends on your browser. In my Chrome it is in the Payload subtab. You can also right click a request and "Copy as Fetch" to get a Javascript call you can translate to Python.

Comment: Thank you very much @AKX. I found out where to look for the post request in Firefox.

Comment: I was trying to implement the above code using torpy, but I am getting an error. I created the TorRequests object `objTorRequest = TorRequests()` and then fetched the Session object `objTorSession = objTorRequest.get_session()` and then I call the get function `objTorResponse = objTorSession.get("https://chartink.com/")`. But I get an error "AttributeError: '_GeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'get'". Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: That'd be a different question, but based on "_GeneratorContextManager" I'd guess you're supposed to use `with objTorRequest.get_session() as sess:`

Comment: Hi! I have posted a new question. Can you please explain why this code will work with the "with statement" only?